# Is the pullback of an adjunction along any functor an adjunction?

Tags: category-theory

In $Cat$: If I take the pullback of a functor which has an adjoint along any functor, does the resulting functor have an adjoint of the same type (left-right)? If yes, does this adjoint behave nicely with regard to the original square, i.e. are there any non-trivial commutativities up to isomorphism?

I actually have more information: My original functor $L : A \to Z$ is a section of its right-adjoint $R$, with unit the identity. Now taking the pullback $L' : Z' \to B$ of $L$ along some functor $F : B \to Z$, it follows from the pullback property that $L'$ is the section of some functor $R' :B \to  Z'$. I would already be happy if this implies that $R'$ is a right adjoint of $L'$.

Comment: Do you have interesting examples to suggest this is true ?

Comment: No. I only have an example in which it would be very handy to use. I won't write it here though, since I would have to do quite a lot of writing to explain why I am interested in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not necessarily. For example, take the inclusion $(1) \to (0\to 1)$ of the terminal object into the category with two objects and a single nonidentity morphism. Its pullback along the inclusion $(0)\to (0\to 1)$ of the initial object is the empty functor $\emptyset\to (0)$, which certainly has no adjoint, since there are no functors $(0)\to \emptyset$; but the inclusion of a terminal object is always right adjoint to the unique functor into the one-point category.

This is to some extent an issue of homotopy theory. The geometric realization of an adjunction between categories is a homotopy equivalence of topological spaces, so one explanation for the fact that this fails is that pullbacks of categories don't always preserve homotopy equivalence of geometric realizations.